# Calcular el promedio de cada operacion hora:minuto:segundo 00::00:00

Tags: powerbi, dax

Como puedo sacar el codigo DAX el promedio de "cada una" de la  **"DESC_OPERACION"** considerando "HOR_INI_OPERAC" , "HOR_FIN_OPERAC" , "DURACION_OPERAC"

Asi mismo esta informacion se encuentra dentro de un tabla de datos en PowerBi llamado OPERADOS_23 la cual tiene las siguientes columnas.

Nota, no sacar el promedio total de todo, si no de cada operacion que se repita.

- HOR_INI_OPERAC = Hora que inicia la operacion
- HOR_FIN_OPERAC   = Horaque termina la operacion
- DURACION_OPERAC  = Duracion total de la operacion

  [https://imgur.com/Rx0c5Qs][1]
  [https://imgur.com/bF5HIhY][1]

*** nota: agrege una nueva columna para sacar

```
TOTAL SEGUNDOS = DATEDIFF('OPERADOS_23'[HOR_INI_OPERAC], 'OPERADOS_23'[HOR_FIN_OPERAC],SECON`D)
```

*** intente con el codigo siguiente

```
Duracion = 
VAR Tiempo = AVERAGE('OPERADOS_23'[TOTAL SEGUNDOS])
VAR Horas = INT(Tiempo /3600)
VAR Minutos = INT((Tiempo - (Horas * 3600)) / 60)
VAR Segundo = MOD(Tiempo, 60)
RETURN
VALUE (Horas & Minutos & Segundo)
```

Pero todas las operacion me sale con una mismo promedio

```
[https://imgur.com/p49vbtN][1]
```